# Trouble with nested range function using variables (VBA/Excel)

Tags: vba, variables, nested, range

I want to define a variable, Xrange, as a dynamic range in my macro. The range itself is made of another variable, xtopcell, which is the top cell in the range. The bottom cell in the range is found using .end(xldown), therefore a nested range is being used. The issue I am having is that an error ("400") occurs when I use the variable xtopcell twice in the nested range. (See code)

```
Set xcolumn = Cells.Find(What:=ComboBox1.Value, After:=Cells(30, 1))
Set xtopcell = xcolumn.Offset(2, 0)
Set Xrange = Range(xtopcell, Range(xtopcell).End(xlDown))
```

If I replace the last line with:

```
Set Xrange = Range(xtopcell, Range("A1").End(xlDown))
```

...then the code will run. But I need to use xtopcell as the range needs to be dynamic.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
Set Xrange = Range(xtopcell, xtopcell.End(xlDown))
```

Inside `Range` you need to specify a name of a range, not the object itself. I hope this makes sense, because it's not an exact explanation.